# how to remove small space that only appear in iphone browser

Tags: iphone, css, html

I am using percentage to define the width of all elements. I am also hiding (`display: none;`) some elements only for handheld, including iphone.

html structure:

```
<header>
    <!-- ... -->
</header>
<nav>
    <!-- ... -->
</nav>
<div id="search">
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/* ... */
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    /* ... */
}

/* ... */
nav {
    float: left;
    width: 76%;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 5px 2%;
}

#search {
    float: right;
    width: 16%;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 5px 2%;
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px), handheld {
    /* ... */
    header {
        height: 50px;
    }
    nav {
        width: 96%; /*plus padding 2% each = 100%*/
    }

    #search {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

So, I am hiding the `search` and increasing the `nav` to fill the space (100%). However, there is a small white space on the right side.

screen view:

[image]

iphone view:

[image]

Does anyone know how to remove the small white space in the iphone view?
The full code: http://jsfiddle.net/AWGk2/

Comment: In your full code there is no white space at corner.. all are working good...

Comment: @Vishal it is working well only for screen view, but not if accessing from iphone. I don't know how to simulate the iphone view, that's why I have included the print screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the padding from your NAV and SEARCH elements.

Make the width of your NAV element 80% and the width of your SEARCH element 20%.

Add a new DIV element inside your NAV and SEARCH elements and apply your padding to those elements. Don't bother specifying a width on these new inner elements.

In your media query section make the NAV width 100%.

I'd also consider adding to your viewport rule.

Here's the one I use myself:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

Comment: @gabrielhilal - I've changed my answer above. Give that a try and see how it goes. It worked okay for me on a test page I made.

Comment: apparently iphone doesn't like `padding` and `margin`... Instead of changing my `nav` and `search` (was messing up the layout), I have created a new `div` around both element with 100% width. So, I have actually followed your idea, but the other way around. many thanks.